# Were there often intra-USSR wars? If not, why not?

Tags: war, soviet-union

There's an article listing many [post-Soviet conflicts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-Soviet_conflicts) on Wikipedia, which indicates that there have been many wars between regions/countries that were once part of the USSR. The causes of the wars, such as ethnicity or religion, often seem timeless (i.e. they ought to have existed during Soviet times too). By implication, that would imply that the USSR itself was a very strained union since its constituents had deep grievances against each other.

Questions:

- Were there regularly such intra-USSR wars before the union dissolved?
- If no, how did the Soviet government stop the wars?

My research seems to show that there was violence, but for some reason it was less common than after the USSR dissolved. For example, there was [fighting in Chechnya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Chechen_War#Soviet_Union) in 1940-1944, but nothing from 1944 to 1991.

Comment: How would that work, when the only military allowed is the Soviet (USSR) Army?

Comment: @T.E.D. I don't know, but it seems that alone shouldn't be sufficient to have no wars - e.g. Chechnya was part of Russia which only had one military, yet two wars were still fought there in post-Soviet times.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're asking about revolts or rebellions as opposed to wars?

Comment: @gktscrk any kind of armed violence between organized factions will do.

Comment: “Pax Romana”. Or in this case, Pax Russa.

Comment: This question seems to be predicated on a model of the USSR as an actual federation of republics; I don't think the evidence supports that model.

Comment: There may be a definition problem here. What, exactly, constitutes a civil war? I would argue that most of Stalin's atrocities, even outside WW II, were acts of war in a very lopsided civil war.

Comment: @KevinKeane definition given above - armed violence between organized factions.

Comment: There was no fighting in Chechnya after 1944 because all Chechens and Ingush (almost 500 000 people) were deported to the Kazakh and Kirghiz SSRs in February - March 1944. Checheno-Ingush Autonomous Soviet Socialist Republic was liquidated. 123,000–200,000 Chechens and Ingush died. Sources are in the wiki page you linked in your question.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: If a misconception is fundamental to the question as a whole, it should probably be addressed/debunked in the answers instead. :)

Comment: @RBarryYoung "Pax Sovietica"

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No, there weren't any civil wars in the Soviet Union. For a few reasons:

- While the USSR consisted of hundreds of ethnic groups, the Soviet
  ethos put a damping cloth on ethnic conflict. People were Soviets
  and therefore in some sense also equals. Not unlike how the US is
  held together by American patriotism.
- The USSR dissolved before political Islam became a driving
  force. The war in Afghanistan was a precursor of things to come, but
  by 1991 political Islam had apparently not penetrated the USSR. Most
  likely, because the secular state worked well-enough for the people
  in the Muslim provinces. Had the USSR survived beyond 1991, perhaps
  the Chechen war would have been its first civil war since then
  1920s. **Update**: No, political Islam isn't new; tensions between the secular and the religious have existed in Muslim countries for the last hundred years. However, due various events - the failure of secular Arab regimes, the Iranian revolution, American-Israeli belligerency, etc - it metastasized in the 1980s and became more dominant. This led to greater unease among Central Asian and Caucasian Muslims to live under secular rule, which in turn lead to demands for autonomy and/or sovereignty, ethnic conflicts, and civil wars. While it is contrafactual history, it is obvious that the same ethnic conflicts would have afflicted the USSR had it survived past 1991. For details, see Sebastien Peyrouse's [article](https://www.hudson.org/research/9892-the-rise-of-political-islam-in-soviet-central-asia) about political Islam in the USSR and John Esposito's [article](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a426734.pdf) about political Islam in general.
- In some sense, the USSR was a colonial empire and the Russians its
  colonial masters. Often not thought of in that way because its
  territory was contiguous, but the enormous distances proves it; the
  distance from Moscow to Vladivostok is roughly the same as from
  London to Mumbai. However, unlike Britain's relationship with India,
  the USSR's relationship with its provinces weren't as
  exploitative. Before the Russian colonization the Far East was
  impoverished. The Russians brought technology and developed the
  infrastructure.
- World War II deeply affected everyone in the Soviet Union. The war, and
  "the great leader", the Georgian Josef Stalin, were unifying forces.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the USSR had a big army and for most of its existence wasn't afraid to use it. Once it developed a bit of a conscience and declined to crush, e.g., Solidarity, it fell apart. This was only a factor in the collapse, but not a small one, I think.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikhail_Gorbachev#The_nationality_question_and_the_Eastern_Bloc

Comment: *"The Russians brought technology and developed the infrastructure"* - that was true to British and French colonies as well, so that's not a difference. And speaking of exploitation, so much food was confiscated from Ukraine by the Soviets that several millions died of starvation.

Comment: @vsz: While it is true that the British and French also brought technology to their colonies, the Soviets integrated the local population into the Soviet system. If we think of the experience [Ghandi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahatma_Gandhi#Civil_rights_activist_in_South_Africa_(1893–1914)) had within the British Empire; I suspect that the Soviet Union was a more inclusive society.

Comment: *The USSR dissolved before political Islam became a driving force.* That's kind of circular. Wahhabism has roots in the 18th century, the Muslim brotherhood was founded in 1928, the modern kingdom of Saudi Arabia in 1932, Pakistan in 1947 and the Islamic revolution in Iran took place in 1978-1979 so political Islam was a force to reckon with during the whole existence of the Soviet Union.

Comment: Force, yes, "reckoned with", no. Up until the Iranian revolution, Islamists *generally* lacked popular support and abstained from politics. Western obliviousness is demonstrated by the fact that Israel supported Hamas and the US the Afghan Mujahideen. Islamism that grew up in the 1980s is qualitatively different from earlier periods. And, of course, the USSR propped up the Islamists opponents.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist I already mentioned the Muslim Brotherhood, Saudi Arabia and especially Pakistan. Islamism is inherently a political movement and it was already very strong (and, indeed, popular, though that wasn't my point). That you didn't hear about it in the media or it didn't reach European consciousness is irrelevant, that's a very superficial and parochial perspective, which completely fails to explain why it did or didn't have influence in the Soviet Union (for, as I just showed, it didn't appear out of nowhere in the 1980s, let alone in the 1990s).

Comment: "*the Soviet ethos put a damping cloth on ethnic conflict. People were Soviets and therefore in some sense also equals*" - you clearly haven't lived in Caucasus during the USSR. Sure, armed conflicts would have been suppressed, but nationalism and xenophobia were ubiquitous. And, not sure about Caucasus, but the Baltic republics definitely regarded USSR as the occupant.

Comment: @Relaxed The MB was an inward looking Muslim organization and it wasn't until 1980s that it became involved in politics. Pakistan was the exception and few other Muslim countries went the Islamic route after decolonization. Saudi Arabia is run by a royal family that the Islamists deeply oppose so idk what your point is. That Islamism became (much) more involved in worldly politics in the 1980s is a well-established fact and not a figment of my imagination. You should post a question if you want more details.

Comment: @BjornLindqvist I'm sorry.  I seem to recall the coup against King Farouk was in 1952, which considerably predated the 1980s.

Comment: I have no idea what the 1952 Egyptian coup led by army officers and supported by the CIA have to do with Islamism.

Comment: @Relaxed How is it circular?

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist “MB was an inward looking Muslim organization”, not sure what you mean with that, it was a political movement from the start. The House of Saud has also been intimately linked with Wahhabism for over a century, if you don't know what my point is, perhaps you have no business discussing the topic. You seem to have an incredibly narrow definition of Islamism as “Al Qaeda and its ilk” and political influence as “being noticed in Europe”. I don't need to ask a question about Islamism if it's to get more ignorant commentary of this caliber.

Comment: @Relaxed Being both rude and ignorant is not a great combination. The MB was indeed an inward-looking movement that tried to influence society outside of the political arena. The Saudi royal family is not Islamist. In fact, the conservative laws implemented in the 1980s were a move *to appease* the Islamists.

Comment: Hopefully a moderator will move this discussion to chat. It is very tangential to my answer and you are essentially nitpicking on the semantic meaning of "driving force".

Comment: I am not nitpicking the meaning of “driving force”, I am pointing out a fundamental misunderstanding of the history of political Islam that leads to a conclusion that is completely wrong (that it appeared out of nowhere in the 1990s and couldn't have impacted the Soviet Union before). Your account of Saudi history is a case in point. Have you heard the word “Wahhabism” before? Are you denying the House of Saud had anything to do with it or used Islam to buttress its power?

Comment: @vsz the confiscation of food had possibly not economic exploitation as the target but the extermination of Ukrainians. The matter is subject to debate.

Comment: @Nguyen while Ukrainians suffered greatly from hunger, calling Golodomor a kind of genocide is somewhat unfounded. Similar famines occurred during Soviet times in other republics, including Russia. However, Soviet ideology proclaimed rich peasants, "kulaks" to be the exploiters, enemy of the common people, and the share of rich peasants was greater in Ukraine and South Russia, so that was one cause of Ukraine's troubles.

Comment: @Nguyen But then Björn Lindqvist's point would have to be "There were no intra-USSR wars because, rather than exploitative as the British relation to India, it was downright genocidal." That's a very different argument to "It was so benign that there were no wars."

Comment: @IMil That's an interesting point - Is it still genocide if I just want to kill enough of a people to force them to submission, rather than to exterminate them?

Comment: I'm accepting your answer now because, based on the source I saw in my answer, your answer is correct.

Answer (score 45):

Yes, there were insurgencies, wars and inter-ethnic conflicts. Not often.

First of all, the [Yakut revolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yakut_revolt) which was part of the Russian civil war, lasted till June 16, 1923. The USSR was established on December 29, 1922. So, the Russian civil war continued in the USSR.

Second, consider the [Basmachi movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basmachi_movement), which lasted till 1934 but in the 1930s was mostly fought in Afghanistan.

The West Ukrainian and Baltic armed insurgencies lasted till the 1950s.

There was an [Armenia-Azerbaijan conflict](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Nagorno-Karabakh_War) started in 1988 with deportations and pogroms, with first artillery involvement in 1990.

Comment: There were also military operations against civilians with dozens of deaths in Tbilisi in 1989 and in Vilnius in early 1991. There was of course the coup in 1991. Not sure if they count.

Comment: According to WP, armed conflict in South Ossetia brgan before the end of the Soviet Union: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/1991%E2%80%931992_South_Ossetia_War . Abkhazia had seen riots with more than a dozen deaths in 1989, but only escalated into a full-blown war in 1992.

Comment: Any idea why these wars and insurgencies were less common during Soviet times as opposed to post-Soviet times? It seems there was nothing from the 1950s to late 1990s too.

Comment: Not the same as intended, which is armed conflicts between the various SSRs. Which were impossible as all armed forces were under direct control of Moscow (either the MoD or the KGB).

Comment: @jwenting: Chechnya and Transnistria were not between different former Soviet Republics. Abkhazia and South Ossetia in the 1990s were not really, either. Or at least not officially. Or the civil war in Tajikistan.

Comment: @Allure: At the end of the 80s, nationalist propaganda became easier due to liberalization. In the early 90s, the security situation became less stable due to the breakup of the Soviet Union and the resulting breakup of the Soviet Army and law enforcement.

Comment: @Allure: or see pjc50's answer

Comment: One more mention from Kazakhstan at least of which I know: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeltoqsan. These are riots happened in the capital of KazSSR in 1986 (the events also featured giving out alkohol for free to students and raising anti-russian violence).

Comment: It might also be fair to consider conflict on territory which was reallocated under Soviet control, e.g. the Eastern part of Poland.

Comment: @Mark Morgan Lloyd The eastern part of Poland, annexed to the USSR is called "Western Ukraine", and it is already mentioned.

Answer (score 17):

Answering Allure's sub-question:

> Any idea why these wars and insurgencies were less common during Soviet times as opposed to post-Soviet times? It seems there was nothing from the 1950s to late 1990s too

The period of 1950-1990 was the "cold war", and was characterised by a high level of militarisation. The security and integrity of the state and Party - and the satellite states such as Hungary - was the top priority.

In order to have a civil war two things are required: something to fight with (weapons), and something to fight for (organisation and ideology). Both of these were subject to incredibly heavy levels of control.

Military discipline was strong, so there was little leakage of weapons into private hands. In the post-Soviet period, many weapons were simply sold on the black market by the officers that were supposedly responsible for them. Also, since the USSR was extremely concerned about Western infiltration, and escaping dissidents, the borders were very tightly controlled making it difficult to infiltrate weapons. "The Iron Curtain" described the seemingly-impenetrable border between the West and the Soviet satellite states of Eastern Europe.

Ideological and informational control was also very strong. The opportunities for *samizdat* publication of political material were limited. Anyone attempting to organize a faction that might fight would be likely to be caught and severely punished.

Finally, to fight you must have an enemy, and two enemies readily existed: for those that believed the propaganda, they could unite against the West. For those that didn't, the biggest and most immediate omnipresent enemy was the state of the USSR itself. In both cases fighting one's immediate neighbors looks like less of a priority.

The risk of individual military units going rogue was mitigated by the usual tactic of empires: conscripts were split up and geographically distributed producing multi-ethnic units that had no particular loyalty to the region they were stationed in.

Comment: Yes, it's a valid point. Many who were in prison/Gulag and left memoirs ([Solzhenitsyn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleksandr_Solzhenitsyn), [Ginzburg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yevgenia_Ginzburg), [Bukovsky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Bukovsky)) remember a distinct section of militant "nationalists" (Ukranian, Baltic, etc.) - true ones, not just someone accused of nationalism (which was a popular conviction at times). For all of them, the enemy was the USSR itself, not their neighbours. / I wouldn't call military discipline "strong", but "leakage of weapons" was indeed minimal.

Answer (score 13):

Sorry for bad English. I am Russian and live in Russia. The USSR consisted of 1/7 of the Earth and included a huge number of peoples of both Europe and Asia. Despite this, there were no serious conflicts during the Soviet regime. It's all about total control over society and anti-religious policy. The USSR was an atheistic state, where a struggle was waged against all religions. Also, the words "Russian", "Uzbek", "Armenian", "Ukrainian" and others were replaced with one word - "Soviet". The state pursued a policy of equalizing people not only in the social sphere, where everyone had almost equal rights, regardless of nationality, but in national issues it carried out education of equality between people of different ethnic origins (although some small nations had more rights than large ones). With the collapse of the USSR, all internal politics and ideology collapsed, parts of the USSR ceased to be different from the rest of the World. The socialist glue, with the support of the Russian nation, ceased to hold back historical conflicts. And some conflicts between nations have more than 800 years of history.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116884/discussion-on-answer-by-hasan-sm-were-there-often-intra-ussr-wars-if-not-why-n).

Answer (score 9):

#### Because of the examples of what happened to anyone who tried

It's easy to forget just how repressive the Soviet regime was.

In the Baltic states, [a guerrilla insurgency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forest_Brothers) operated throughout WWII and into the 1950s.  Fighters attempted to kill themselves rather than be captured, because anyone captured by the Soviets would usually be tortured to death.

In 1953, [East Germans protested against Soviet rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_German_uprising_of_1953).  The USSR sent the army in.  The protests mostly crumbled before serious bloodshed happened, although there were "example" executions of leaders.

In 1956, [the Hungarian revolution against Soviet rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_Revolution_of_1956) was crushed by overwhelming military force.  This time the Soviets didn't hold back and thousands died.

In 1968, [the Soviet Army invaded Czechoslovakia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warsaw_Pact_invasion_of_Czechoslovakia) to stamp out political movements for increased autonomy.  Mostly the Czechs did not resist violently, because the lessons from Hungary were clear.

And throughout the span of the USSR, any dissent was generally punished with forced labour in [gulags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulag), and a general loss of what rights you did have.  This often extended to families as well.

Comment: Using French colonial rule as a point of comparison, they were certainly willing to execute dissidents and militarily crush revolts. Some explanation is needed for why western European use of violence was so much less effective at deterring revolt. It's certainly not a reluctance to kill their subjects; compare the Algerian war with 300k-1.5 M estimated dead to the Hungarian revolution with 3k.

Comment: It's not exactly a good comparison though - first, East Germany, Hungary and Czechoslovakia weren't part of the USSR, and second, wars have happened where the dissenters know they will probably die if caught, but are hoping not to get caught (e.g. Zelimkhan Yandarbiyev from the Chechen wars). Was the USSR a lot more effective than the post-Soviet states at catching dissenters?

Comment: @Allure USSR didn't just punish dissenters - it also punished their families, sometimes to quite a big extent. It's quite a different proposal to throw away your life for an ideal, and to throw away your future (i.e. kids), and all the people you care about. And people were quite ready to tell on their neighbours and even family if they did or planned something anti-state. That probably isn't enough on its own to explain the _relative_ stability, but add all the other things (e.g. USSR trying to stamp out nationalism and religion etc.)...

Comment: @Luaan hmm I know imperial China also punished dissenters' families, but there were lots of revolutions in China's history. It could be just a matter of perspective though, since China has over 2000 years of recorded history, while the Soviet Union's relative peace lasted only ~40 years.

Answer (score 4):

Just quick addition to Anixx answer

- There was a conflict in 1990 between Uzbeks and the Kyrgyz population in [Osh Kirghiz SSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osh_riots_(1990))

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Soviet Union kept peace by damping out nationalism. Near the end of the cold war, when Gorbachev allowed nationalism, was when the setting for post-Soviet conflicts took root.

> [Azerbaijan-Armenia] hatreds are not ancient: The first large-scale ethnic clashes between Armenians and Azerbaijanis took place as late as in 1905, during a period of turmoil born from modernization within the Russian Empire. They are, instead, based on the grievances, and the particular forms of nationalism that emerged after the fall of the Soviet Union. These might have been slightly open to negotiation at that time; they have, by now, crystallized into two identities that are radically incompatible and contradictory, among peoples most of whom have never met anyone from “the other side” in real life.
>
> As a result, the other is routinely de-humanized through a number of hateful stereotypes. To Armenians, Azerbaijanis are “Turks”: nomadic Central Asian intruders into the region engaged in a millennium-long effort to drive them out through massacre and misrule. Inferences are made about a purported “Turkish psychology” prone to such violent behavior; and Azerbaijanis are seen as unsophisticated, and lacking in indigenous culture. Their existence as a real ethnic group before 1918 – the founding of the first independent Azerbaijani republic – is denied. The cultural legacy of their ancestors – like the Blue Mosque in Yerevan, or the mosques in Karabakh – are ascribed to generic “Muslims,” or the long-time imperial rulers over this region – the Persians.
>
> The Azerbaijani version is a variation on these discourses: Armenians are often portrayed as a rootless nation engaged in an ongoing effort at encroachment into the South Caucasus. They are often generalized as inherently “terroristic”; collectively seen as cunning, devious, culturally parasitical, capable of misleading the world through a diaspora whose (hidden) power is often overstated. Their history in the South Caucasus is also dismissed as a myth. One standard account is of Armenians arriving in the area only in the 19th century, with any Armenian monuments in the region identified as “Caucasian Albanian,” a now-extinct Christian culture seen as part of Azerbaijan’s historic lineage.

[Source](https://eurasianet.org/perspectives-stereotypes-and-hatred-drive-the-nagorno-karabakh-conflict)

In other words, it's only at the end of the Soviet Union that Azerbaijan and Armenia saw each other so negatively. Therefore, the answer to "how did the Soviet government stop the wars?" is "by imposing a uniform national identity".

Answer (score 0):

There were not too many wars and inter-ethnic conflicts inside of the USSR just because anyone who has dissent thoughts was immediately killed or imprisoned during repression years. Also, there were about 10 kgb agents per 100 citizens. So almost all citizens knew enough to be ok with the regime especially not to have any thoughts about ethnic conflicts. But everyone hates another, that appear after the USSR fall.

Answer (score -1):

Holodomor of 1932-33, the Soviet government simply decided to kill the Ukrainians by starvation, taking everything, and closing all borders. All wars in the USSR were resolved by sending all the unwanted to the GULAG. (The Main Directorate of Camps and Places of Detention, emerged in 1930, existed for thirty years, and was liquidated by 1960) The GULAG system in the USSR consisted of 30 thousand places of detention: from the Arctic Circle to Kazakhstan, from the western borders to the Far East. The USSR is a prison power with completely closed borders. The number of prisoners was equal to the number of people living in about two European countries combined, and this does not include prisons. What wars?

Comment: One could argue that taking prisoners (for non-criminal reasons) is an act of war in itself.

Comment: Although these are indeed horrible atrocities, they are not really wars where two armies are fighting each other. And the question was asking about wars, not merely the oppression of civilians outside of a shooting war.